# Enable right-click on a page (or image) of my website

Tags: javascript, image

I discovered this website while stuck on my own website development and couldn't find exactly the answer I am looking for.
I am using Photocrati to build a photographers website, and I need to enable right click on one page so visitors can download free pictures.

The page is the following : https://lacanneetletrepied.com/cadeau/

Unfortunately, the option "enable" or "disable" right click for the whole theme somehow doesn't function as it should. The right click is always disabled no matter how I change it.

This question has already been mainly answered on this topic : [Enable Right Click Wordpress Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36989749/enable-right-click-wordpress-site)
The answer is globally the following : Just remove it from functions.php look for wp_enqueue_script().
But as I am new to website development (and quite new to development in general), I still have questions.

On my website, I press F12 to get the developers panel (on Chrome or Firefox, PC, W10).

But (this is where I am a complete beginner) : where can I find : wp_enqueue_script(), functions.php and how do I remove a JavaScript from there ?

Also, is mentionned the code : var photocrati_image_protection_global = {"enabled":"1"};
I can't find it either in the developers tab. Where can it be ? Do I need to both remove the JS and change the code ?

And finally, how can I make this modification happen only on the page I mentioned above ?

Finally, If you have a simple option to enable right click on the images of this page (https://lacanneetletrepied.com/cadeau/) , I would gladly take it :)

Thank you so much for your help.

Cypus

Comment: `Unfortunately, the option "enable" or "disable" right click for the whole theme somehow doesn't function as it should.` You need to contact theme support and find where exactly YOUR theme is failing to disable/enable right click. Other topics wont help. And you can not do anything  from devtools. You need learn the basic and learn how to edit files on your server or database if needed.  Anyway your theme support is way to go.

Comment: Allright, thanks for the advice. I contacted them and waiting for the answer.